# Adding URL Parameters to a link within a document jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

I'm having trouble, grabbing the parameters from a link and appending them to the end of the link. I can change the text of an element but not the attribute. See my not working example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var urlParams = window.location.search;
            if (urlParams) {
                // remove leading '?' if present
                var cleanUrlParams = (urlParams[0]=='?') ? urlParams.substring(1, urlParams.length) : urlParams;

                // remove leading and trailing '&' if present
                var cleanUrlParams = (cleanUrlParams[0]=='&') ? cleanUrlParams.substring(1, cleanUrlParams.length) : cleanUrlParams;
                var cleanUrlParams = (cleanUrlParams[cleanUrlParams.length - 1]=='&') ? cleanUrlParams.substring(0, cleanUrlParams.length - 1) : cleanUrlParams;

                // include only the url params with values
                var includeUrlParams = "";
                var urlParamPairs = cleanUrlParams.split("&");
                for (var i = 0; i < urlParamPairs.length; i++) {
                    var splitUrlParamPair = urlParamPairs[i].split("=");
                    if ((splitUrlParamPair.length == 2) && (splitUrlParamPair[1].length > 0)) {
                        if (includeUrlParams.length > 0) {
                            includeUrlParams = includeUrlParams + "&";
                        }
                        includeUrlParams = includeUrlParams + urlParamPairs[i];
                    }
                }

                // if there are url parameters then append them to something in the DOM
                if (includeUrlParams.length > 0) {
                    $(".editMyUrlParams").attr("href" + includeUrlParams);
                }
            }
        });
```

And then calling it like this

```
<a class="editMyUrlParams" href="http://thisisawebsite.com/">This is a link</a>
```

This is where I go wrong I think. If I change the following to text - it works

```
if (includeUrlParams.length > 0) {
                    $(".editMyUrlParams").text("There are the params: " + includeUrlParams);
                }
```

So I know I'm missing something where I can append the attributes to the end of the href and get a result like this

```
<a class="editMyUrlParams" href="http://thisisawebsite.com/?param1=this1&param2=this2">This is a link</a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$(".editMyUrlParams").attr('href', $(".editMyUrlParams").attr('href') + stringToAppend);
```

Or better:

```
var $elements = $(".editMyUrlParams");
var oldHrefValue = $elements.attr('href');
var newHrefValue = oldHrefValue + stringToAppend;
$elements.attr('href', newHrefValue);
```